# Can't get custom fields of a woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i am trying to get the custom fields with this function and multiply by the product price. I am getting the product price but when printing the custom fields, i am only getting zeros.. i dont understand why, i had tryed `get_metadata()` and `get_post_custom()` too.. but nothing works

```
    function filter_woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal( $product_subtotal, $product, $quantity, $instance ) { 
        $fields = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), false);
        $add_on = $product->get_price()*$fields[0] + $product->get_price()*$fields[1] + $product- 
                  >get_price()*0.75*$fields[2];

        return $product_subtotal + $add_on; 
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', 10, 4 );
```

I have tryed to get single fields too but always getting zeros.

I can get the custom fields in function below and save it in a global variable but when i try to access the global variable in the function above, i get zero again.

```
function tour_product_add_on_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id, $cart ){
/*
if( isset( $_POST['time_add_on'] ) ) {
    $cart_item['time_add_on'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['time_add_on'] );
}
*/
if( isset( $_POST['date_add_on'] ) ) {
    $cart_item['date_add_on'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['date_add_on'] );
}
if( isset( $_POST['place_add_on'] ) ) {
    $cart_item['place_add_on'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['place_add_on'] );
}
if( isset( $_POST['adult_add_on'] ) ) {
    $cart_item['adult_add_on'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['adult_add_on'] );
}
if( isset( $_POST['child_add_on'] ) ) {
    $cart_item['child_add_on'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['child_add_on'] );
}
if( isset( $_POST['infant_add_on'] ) ) {
    $cart_item['infant_add_on'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['infant_add_on'] );
}
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $GLOBALS["fee"] = $_POST['adult_add_on']*$product->get_price() + 
 $_POST['child_add_on']*$product->get_price() + $_POST['infant_add_on']*0.75*$product->get_price();
    return $cart_item;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`get_post_meta()` second parameter is the meta key value. So you should use for example
`$date_add_on = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'date_add_on')`

Comment: Yeah, i have tryed to get single fields with key like `get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'date_add_on', true)` but get zeros too

Comment: Try using `$product->get_id()` as the id

Comment: Yeah, i have tryed that too, still not working. With `get_the_id()` and `$product->get_id()` getting the same id.

Comment: Have you tried `$date_add_on= $product->get_meta('date_add_on', true );`  OR

`// Creating an object instance of the product
$_product = new WC_Product( $product_id );

// getting the defined product attributes
$product_attr = $_product->get_attributes();

// displaying the array of values (just to test and to see output)
echo var_dump( $product_attr )`

Comment: `product_attr` returns `array(0) { }`

Comment: I am reading that you have to add custom fields to a products and save them. I have only added it to cart and the order, that's the problem?

Comment: Yes. If you want this product to have different attributes in this particular order then you have to change order line_item meta fields. But as you want it shown before the purchase has been made you need to get the current order in cart to your function and then check for the values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924998/change-cart-items-subscription-properties-values-before-checkout Check this for example

Answer (score 0):

So, i have resolved this issue. When you add a custom field to a woocommerce product or a wordpress post, you have to update it's meta data. Here is a good tutorial of every step you have to follow to add a custom field.

[HOW TO ADD WOOCOMMERCE CUSTOM FIELDS TO A PRODUCT](https://pluginrepublic.com/add-custom-fields-woocommerce-product/)